# Campo de pesquisa de jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Estou utilizando o componente jQuery Datatable. Na visualização no computador a tabela com o campo de pesquisa está ok, mas ao visualizar no celular o campo ultrapassa o painel onde está inserido, como pode ser visualizado na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Tenta isso no seu CSS: `input[type="search"]{ max-width: 10%; }`... a intenção é deixar muito pequeno para ver se surte efeito... aí vc aumenta esse valor de 10% até ficar no tamanho ideal.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insira no seu CSS uma estilo para limitar a largura do `input`:

```
input[type="search"]{
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

O seletor `input[type="search"]` pega o elemento de busca padrão do Datatables. Ajuste o valor de `80%` para mais ou para menos conforme não ultrapasse o painel.